# Redis won't work on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, redis, rabbitmq, macos-sierra

After installing rabbitmq server and docker, I tried to run my node script which listens on port 6379 for `kue` usage on localhost, but I keep getting this error:

```
    events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1059:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
```

Is my rabbitmq working? Yes:

```
    ~rabbitmq-server

              RabbitMQ 3.6.4. Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.
  ##  ##      Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
  ##  ##
  ##########  Logs: /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
  ######  ##        /usr/local/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log
  ##########
              Starting broker...
 completed with 10 plugins
```

So what is wrong here? Is the port closed? If so, how can I open it?

Answer (score 1):

and there was an answer I found on github...
`docker run --name redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis` and it works now..